White pill button iOS 18
I’ve been working on an app using MAUI and am doing testing on various platforms.
I’ve noticed a strange white pill button has decided to appear below the multitasking dots in my TitleBar of the app.
Relatively new to developing for iOS and wondered if anyone could shed light on what is causing this?
Not sure if it’s some accessibility feature or something with iOS 18 but the button doesn’t seem to do anything, nor does it show in earlier versions of iOS or on any android devices.
Any advice would be much appreciated!

Tried testing on multiple iOS and android devices/simulators. Only able to replicate on iOS 18.
I created a blank .NET MAUI app on .NET 8.0 and ran on iOS 18 simulator - here is my code from AppShell.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
   x:Class="TestingApp.AppShell"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingApp"
   Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
   Title=""
   Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
   Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false">

   <ShellContent
       Title="How to remove this"
       Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
       Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
       ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
       Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>


Here is another screenshot from test app - Seems to be something to do with the Title in ShellContent??


that appears to be the dynamic island - its a feature of some iOS devices

Hi @Jason thanks for taking time to comment on my question. I’ve tried to look into this and not sure if this is the case?
The UI element in question is showing on physical iPads which to my understanding don’t have this Dynamic Island feature. Plus the shell title seems to be showing inside it - really lost here as just simply want to remove it. Maybe I’m misunderstanding !

Managed to figure this out.
It seems to be that the area in question is actually a "Tab" - eventhough I tried to disable these. It appears Apple changed the way tabs work in iOS 18 and as such I had to use a custom renderer for the AppShell.
Found solution here: Maui: floating tabbar on iPads in iOS 18

In the question there is no tabbar so how to fix it?
